# Partiality Monad Transformer

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to deconstruct the `IResult` monad from [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.10.4.0) into a few pieces. Here's `IResult`

```
data IResult t r = Fail t [String] String
                 | Partial (t -> IResult t r)
                 | Done t r
```

This feels like it ought to be a combination of effects, "partiality" and failure. If failure is represented as just an `Either ([String], String)` then partiality might be

```
data Partiality t a = Now a | Later (t -> Partiality t a)

instance Monad (Partiality t) where
  return = pure
  (Now a) >>= f = f a
  (Later go) >>= f = Later $ \t -> go t >>= f

class MonadPartial t m where
  feed  :: t -> m a -> m a
  final :: m a -> Bool

instance MonadPartial t (Partiality t) where
  feed _ (Now a) = Now a
  feed t (Later go) = go t
  final (Now _) = True
  final (Later _) = False
```

(which gets its namesake from [a paper by Danielsson](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-semantics-partiality-monad.pdf) when you use `Partiality ()`)

I could use `Partiality` as a base monad, but is there a `PartialityT` monad transformer?

Comment: What is your monad instance for `Partiality t`?

Comment: Added to the main question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There sure is!  Your `Partiality` monad is a free monad:

```
import Control.Monad.Free  -- from the `free` package

type Partiality t = Free ((->) t)
```

... and the corresponding `PartialityT` is a free monad transformer:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free  -- also from the `free` package

type PartialityT t = FreeT ((->) t)
```

Here's an example program showing how you would use it:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free

type PartialityT t = FreeT ((->) t)

await :: (Monad m) => PartialityT t m t
await = liftF id

printer :: (Show a) => PartialityT a IO r
printer = forever $ do
    a <- await
    lift $ print a

runPartialityT :: (Monad m) => [a] -> PartialityT a m r -> m ()
runPartialityT as p = case as of
    []   -> return ()
    a:as -> do
        x <- runFreeT p
        case x of
            Pure _ -> return ()
            Free k -> runPartialityT as (k a)
```

We build the free monad transformer using the `await` command to request new values and `lift` to invoke actions in the base monad.  We get the `Monad` and `MonadTrans` instances for `PartialityT` for free, because the free monad transformer is automatically a monad and monad transformer for any given functor.

We run the above program like so:

```
>>> runPartialityT [1..] printer
1
2
3
...
```

I recommend you read [this post I wrote about free monad transformers](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/free-monad-transformers.html).  However, the new official home of the free monad transformer is the `free` package.

Also, if you are looking for an effectful incremental parser, I'm about to release that as the `pipes-parse` package within a few days.  You can check the [current draft here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Parse-Library).

Comment: Oh, of course it is! My flaw was that I couldn't figure out where the inner monadic layers ought to be and defined `data PartialityT t m a = PT { runPT :: m (Partiality t a) }`... which only gives me a single inner monadic layer! Thanks for the push in the right direction (and the resultant obvious generalization!)